# Updating application on PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

I updating app on play store, and I implemented AdBuddiz before this process. I recieved message: 
"You uploaded an APK that no permit for a fee or a permit for the collection of which is limited to certain versions of the SDK . Permission for the collection is necessary for the sale of products offered by the application. “

How can I fix that?

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: Is that what the message said _word for word_, _in English_?

Comment: Yes, or my automatic translate is bad?

Comment: It's work now by miracle :)